# How to Parse webflow with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, parsing, annotations, jaxb

I use Spring webflow and I need to read flow definition
this flow definition is a xml file...
I want to parse this XML with JAXB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd" 
        parent="global-flow" >

    <subflow-state id="aaaa" subflow="test/test19/aaaa">
        <transition on="torna" to="verificaPef" />
        <transition on="prosegui" to="bbbb" />
    </subflow-state>

    <subflow-state id="bbbb" subflow="test/test19/bbbb">
        <transition on="torna" to="aaaa" />
        <transition on="prosegui" to="end" />
    </subflow-state>

    <subflow-state id="cccc" subflow="common/cccc/page">
        <transition on="torna" to="bbbbb" />
    </subflow-state>
</flow>
```

I try this mapping:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "flow", namespace = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow")
public class Flow {

  @XmlElement(name = "subflow-state")
  private List<SubFlow> subFlowList;

  @XmlAttribute
  private String parent;

...
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SubFlow {

  @XmlAttribute(name="id")
  private String id;

  @XmlAttribute(name="subflow")
  private String subflow;
```

but don't work!!!
the subFlowList list always empty (null)
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@XmlSchema` annotation to set a namespace, and an elementFormDefault to control the namespace qualification.

**package-info**

You can do this by adding a class called package-info in the same package as your domain classes.

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

**Flow**

This will enable you to remove other namespace information you may have previously added.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Flow {

  @XmlElement(name = "subflow-state")
  private List<SubFlow> subFlowList;

  @XmlAttribute
  private String parent;

  ...

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html